# Hovering over button in one window shows up in the other window - Tkinter

Tags: python, class, button, tkinter, hover

What I intended was to create two separate windows with two separate buttons. If you hover over one button, the button changes colour. If you hover over the other button, that button changes colour.

However, what I get is when I hover over the button first generated, it changes the colour of the second button instead. The second button, however, behaves as it should. Either way, only the second button shows any change.

How do I stop this strange cross-window interaction?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, playerName, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(playerName)

    def hover_in(self, num):
        if self.button["bg"] == "lightblue":
            self.button["bg"] = "white"

    def hover_out(self, num):
        if self.button["bg"] == "white":
            self.button["bg"] = "lightblue"

    def create(self):
        Player.button = Button(self.window, text="Hover", bg="lightblue", width=40)
        Player.button.grid()
        i=10
        Player.button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, num=i: Player.hover_in(self, num))
        Player.button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, num=i: Player.hover_out(self, num))

b1 = Toplevel()
b2 = Toplevel()

p1 = Player("Player 1", b1)
p1.create()
p2 = Player("Player 2", b2)
p2.create()
root.withdraw()

root.mainloop()
```

Edits: Minor code changes that make more sense

Edit 2: Re-introduced num variable which was part of my original code

Edit 3: Undid all edits as errors were being produced

Comment: In create(), why are you using ```Player.button```?  Why not ```self.button```?

Comment: I should probably change that, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @ewong Actually, changing `Player` to `self` generates errors such as `TypeError: hover_out() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: @ewong Forgive me, I didn't read your comment properly... self.button works fine

Answer (score 0):

Changing Player.button to self.button solved the issue. Thank you @ewong